# Problems out of my machine: how to debug outside a dev environment?

Tags: c++, windows, debugging

I'm developing an application in 3D in a win 7 64bits machine, in visual C++ 2008. All runs correctly. When I check this application in a clean machine in a VMWare virtual machine with XP 32bits (hardware 3D activated) or in a machine of a friend of mine, the application fails.

The behavior of the application is different (into the clean machine) depending of the compilation (debug or release) and if I compile with MD(d) or MT(d)

My question: it is possible to debug the application into the clean machine? Exists a central log like /var/log/message but in windows? How to check what dll are in use in my dev machine, in order to compare with the installed in the clean machine?

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio 2008 as well? If so, are you using at least Professional edition? If you are, you can set up [Remote Debugging](http://tinyurl.com/27hsrlt)

Comment: i am so bummed that they removed ntsd.exe from fresh windows installs. wtf mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its on the same network you can you the remote debugger ! But you may first want to check if its not a 64bit app on a 32bit OS.

Comment: Yeah! is the same machine. I'm using VMware player, and the "clean machine" is hosted in my dev machine. I'll try remote debugger.

Comment: if it's on the same machine (dual boot) then can't you do a network install of Visual studio ,then you have all your tools at hand on XP.

Comment: Sorry didn't read comment well ! Please ,ignore my last comment. I am not familiair with VMware

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the bitness is correct and that the correct VC++ distributable is installed on the test machines.

If that doesn't help, then try this for fast debugging:

Grab the debugging toolkit from MS (http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx)

Install it on your development machine.

Copy the installation folder to the machine you want to debug on.

Copy / Install your program to the machine, remember the *.PDB files.

Start WinDBG from the debugger folder and use the 'File->Open executable' command to start your app. WinDGB will break fast and you can debug from there.

If you want break points and such, look up the commands in the WinDBG help files.

Comment: Its not the distributable, AFAIK. When you start the program without distributable content installed, a message appears asking for a reinstallation as a solution. But in my case, the error I'm chasing is like "the system has requested for termination....". Like an assert, but in release mode.

Comment: Then you have to swing a debugger at it. WinDBG should break at the exception that causes the program to shutdown, but it can be somewhat hairy to use for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

You could try running your app under dependency walker (www.dependencywalker.com). If the problem is missing or incorrect dlls, dependency walker will show it up very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

On XP you can use the built-in debugger, `ntsd.exe`. it's basically like windbg lite and requires no additional install.